# How to run dlib package in buildozer?

Tags: android, python, kivy, dlib, buildozer

I am new to Android app development and I'm creating a facial recognition app with kivy and buildozer. To be able to use the dlib package, how should I modify the buildozer.spec file? Is it enough to simply add dlib to the requirements line? Dlib has many dependencies that cannot be installed with pip (Cmake,Boost, Boost.python, X11), and I'm not sure whether or not python-for-android had recipes for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only pure-Python packages can be plainly added with modifying `buildozer.spec` file. If module contains binaries or code that should be compiled to binary, it must have python-for-android recipe that will compile this module (and it's dependencies) for Android properly. List of available p4a recipes you can see [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes). There's no recipe for `dlib`: you can either try to write your recipe based on existing (but it would be hard IMHO) or, for example, try to search for some alternative. May be [face recognition](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) with OpenCV (that already [has](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/opencv) recipe)? Note, I didn't try it myself.

Comment: I tried using OpenCV as an alternative to dlibs but ran into some errors...Wrote a separate question about it in case you want to take a look (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072091/buildozer-numpy-runtimeerror-broken-toolchain-cannot-link-a-simple-c-program). I wrote about numpy in the question but opencv gave me the exact same error.